# What are risks of disabling SIP for OpenCore Legacy Patcher: UNAUTHENTICATED_ROOT?

Tags: macos, security, software-update, sip

In order to keep MacOS updated on older Mac, OpenCore Legacy Patcher needs to lift next System Integrity Protections:

- UNAUTHENTICATED_ROOT
- UNRESTRICTED_FS
- UNTRUSTED_KEXTS

What do they allow and what are potential risks of it? Namely the UNAUTHENTICATED_ROOT looks dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNAUTHENTICATED_ROOT just disables SSV (Signed System Volume). SSV makes it so that if any modifications are made to the Root Volume, then it won't be bootable anymore.

Normally, this would be a good security measure against some attacks, but it's also a hindrance for if you're patching with OCLP. If you're using Root Volume Patches, and you enable SSV, you may render your root volume unbootable and need to reinstall macOS using recovery or a bootable installer.

UNRESTRICTED_FS disables filesystem restrictions. I'm pretty sure this allows you to modify directories that are usually protected, even from root access.

UNTRUSTED_KEXTS allows you to install untrusted kexts to /System/Library/Extensions. In the case of OCLP, this allows you to install graphics driver patches to modern OS versions.

If your SIP settings are set to 0x803, you WILL want to leave it as-is. This is so that you can install root volume patches on your Mac.